# How to pass @Input() decorator value to its html file?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6

I have main app.component.ts,from here i am passing the currentstatus variable to the chid component(Navbar Component) which is navbar.component.ts and i have passed the value to the Navbar component using @input() decorator but I am getting problem how to pass this value of input decorator to navbar.component.html?

My main `app.component.ts` is

```
export class AppComponent {

      public currentstatus: any;

      constructor(private authService:LoginAuthService,private router:Router){
           this.currentstatus=this.authService.getStatus().
           subscribe(currentstatus => {
            this.currentstatus=currentstatus;
           })
      }

      logout(){
        localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
        this.router.navigate(['login']);
      }
```

From here i am passing  this currentstatus

My `app.component.html` is

```
<div id = "wrapper">
    <div class="main-page">
<app-navbar [currentstatus]="currentstatus" ></app-navbar>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>
</div>
</div>
```

here i have passed the currentstatus to navbar.component.ts

```
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() currentstatus:any;


   constructor(){

  }
  ngOnInit() {
  }

  logout(){

  }
}
```

now how to pass this currentstatus to navbar.component.html???

Comment: What do you mean by "I am getting problem how to pass..." . Do you have an error in console ? It seems to me you are using the correct way of passing a value to a child component.

Comment: As a general recommendation, you could put the loading part in a `ngOnInit` function of the AppComponent (and mark the class as `implements OnInit`). But I don't think this will solve your issue.

Comment: Jsut print so: `{{currentstatus}}`

Comment: yes how to use that  @Input() currentstatus:any; inside  ngOnInit function. i am getting confuse in it

Comment: Ohh I see, let me write an answer. Get rid of the `this.currentstatus=` before your call to service.

Comment: just use it as other variables you are using `{{currentstatus}}`

Comment: @YaseenAhmad if it's an object, then OP should use something like : `{{currentstatus | json}}` or `<pre>{{currentstatus | json}}</pre>` to watch a variable in a template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You error was that you are doing something like `abc = service.get().subscribe(result => abc = result;})`

(you are trying to set `currentstatus` **both** as the whole Subscirption *and* as the result of the subscribe)

Just use your service like this :

Either assign to currentstatus the result of your request :

**Possibility 1 :**

AppComponent :

```
this.authService.getStatus().subscribe(
    result =>  { this.currentstatus = result; });
```

**Possibility 2 :**

Or you can use `async` pipe from Angular to do the subscribe for you, in this case currentstatus in the parent app should be the whole Observable (without subscribe), this would give something like :

AppComponent.ts :

```
// assign the Observable to your variable currentstatus
this.currentstatus = this.authService.getStatus();
```

AppComponent.html :

```
<app-navbar [currentstatus]="currentstatus | async"></navbar>
```

**NB :**

Remark for both cases : in general, it's usually best practice to execute service calls in a `ngOnInit` function instead of the constructor.